# Select part of strings more than XX symbols long, not including some text

Tags: regex

I've a text

```
<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

I need to delete all `<tr>...</tr>` parts which is longer than 90 symbols

I tried with this expression `<tr><td>.{90,}?</td></tr>` and it works almost fine, but it can select `<tr>` blocks if they're very short, like this `<tr><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>123</td></tr>`

How I can modify my regex to not include `<tr>` in selection?

Here is sample text https://pastebin.com/4s421RE4

Comment: change the `.` into `[^><]`? anyway it is not good idea to process xml/html by regex.

Comment: tnkx, but notepad++ can't find nothing with this

Comment: Please clarify what it is you want:
a) <tr><td> 90 characters in here </td></tr>
or
b) 90 characters from <tr> to </tr>

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov what I meant is `<tr><td>[^<>]{90,}</td></tr>`

Comment: @garroad_ran - Any variant is acceptable

Comment: @Kent - still can't found nothing, I added  a sample in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line works for your sample data:

```
<tr><td( [^>]*)?>(.(?!</td>)){89,}.</td></tr>
```

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/bmeQNU/1

Comment: Tnkx, for your help, but I modify length to 10 - and nothing is found https://regex101.com/r/qZk9FB/1. But it should select all blocks

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov because your tr contains multiple (td)s, simply: `<tr>(.(?!</tr>)){9,}.</tr>`